# TextView Array is not displaying data

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-layout

I have been working for a few days to have arrays of data be displayed into arrays of TextView. Preferrably I am wanting up to 10 rows of TextViews with 4 columns.

Currently I have the following .java file and it is thorwing a fatal error:

```
public class DebtList extends Activity {
Integer trigger = 5;
Double totalDebt = 0.00;

//TextView dispTotalDebt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dispTotalDebt); 

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.debtlist);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String[] debtNames = new String[10];
    Double[] debtAmount = new Double[10];
    Double[] debtRate = new Double[10];
    Double[] debtTerm = new Double[10];

    debtNames[trigger] = extras.getString("nickname");

    View linearLayout =  findViewById(R.id.debtlist);
    Integer stopper = trigger+1;

    for(int i=0; i < stopper; i++)
    {
        TextView value = new TextView(this);
        value.setText("test" + i); //debtNames[i] later
        value.setId(i);
        value.setTextSize(50);
        value.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(value);

    }

    trigger++;
}
}
```

Here is the .xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/debtlist"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalDebt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Total Debt:" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/dispTotalDebt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and lastly, here is the logcat for when I run this.

```
10-13 02:16:16.785: W/dalvikvm(898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.ActionBar$LayoutParams
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at biz.midl.debttracking.DebtList.onCreate(DebtList.java:42)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-13 02:16:16.795: E/AndroidRuntime(898):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

End result, I want a person to be able to input debt information on Activity (DebtInput.java) which has an intent upon the "add" button being selected. The intent will bring the data tot his activity for display in ADDITION to the old data.

Comment: `android.app.ActionBar` is only present in API level 11. Whatever you're deploying to does not have that class. What are you deploying to?

Comment: level 10 - I'm trying to change my Emulator to 11 but it's giving me problems, I'll post when I have an update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ActionBar is presented in API 11. You can't use it in lower API levels.

See this solution, it may help.

[Table view giving error below API level 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393962/table-view-giving-error-bellow-api-level-11)

Comment: upon upgrading the API to 12 it functions, thank you Justin and Bette for the notification of the error!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your import statements, but you probably get them wrong.

Instead of  *import  ...ViewGroup.LayoutParams* (or LinearLayout.LayoutParams) you may have
*import ActionBar.LayoutParams* which wouldn't work with pre  API 11 (and this is just wrong,
because  ActionBar.LayoutParams is incompatible with LinearLayout.LayoutParams). By changing that
you should get it working with any API, even API 1!

P.S To change target API, go to Project / Properties / Android and pick up target, provided you have corresponding API installed.